# Graficar una Curva Roc en R

Tags: r

Estoy tratando de graficar la curva ROC y encontré el siguiente código ejemplo:

```
library("rpart")
data("kyphosis", package = "rpart")
rp <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ ., data = kyphosis)
library("ROCR")
pred <- prediction(predict(rp, type = "prob")[, 2], kyphosis$Kyphosis)
plot(performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr"))
abline(0, 1, lty = 2)
```

Reproducí las primeras líneas:

```
Ingresantes<- Ingresantes97[,c(2,3,6,10,11,14,25)]

# Crear conjunto de datos de entrenamiento (70%) y de prueba (30%)
set.seed(134)
ind<-sample(2,nrow(Ingresantes),replace = TRUE,prob = c(0.6,0.4))
trainData<-Ingresantes[ind==1,]
testdata<-Ingresantes[ind==2,]

# Crear Modelo de arbol de decisión
ArbolRpart<-rpart(Estado ~ .,method = 'class',data = trainData)

# prueba ROC
library("ROCR")
pred <- prediction(predict(ArbolRpart, type = "prob")[, 2], 
Ingresantes$Estado)
```

y al ejecutar la última línea, de la prueba ROC, me da el siguiente error:
Error in prediction(predict(ArbolRpart, type = "prob")[, 2], Ingresantes$Estado) : 
  Number of predictions in each run must be equal to the number of labels for each run.

Alguien podría orientarme de lo que estoy haciendo mal????.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema lo tienes aquí:

```
pred <- prediction(predict(ArbolRpart, type = "prob")[, 2], Ingresantes$Estado)
```

Estas trabajando con un modelo construido a partir de los datos de `trainData`, pero las etiquetas o labels, los estas tomando de la base completa de observaciones, es decir `Ingresantes`. De ahí el error que no coinciden las cantidades entre las predicciones y las etiquetas. Entiendo que debieras hacer algo así:

```
pred <- prediction(predict(ArbolRpart, type = "prob")[, 2], trainData$Estado)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! ahora funciona  :) . Como no entiendo bien la fórmula de prediction me podrías explicar qué significa [,2]??. Otra vez muchas gracias

Comment: `[,2]` lo copie tal cual de tu código, y significa la selección de la columna 2 del la matriz que retorna `predict`. Saludos.